# ASP.NET: Why can't I call a web-service twice in one page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I built a web-application which calls a web-service twice in the application's log-in page - first, on Page_Load, and the second time is after a button click.
When debugging, everything goes well, but after publishing the web-application and trying it - I cannot make the two calls for the web-service (each call is invoking a different function in the same web-service).

If I call it once (say, in the Page_Load) its OK, but once I get to the button click event, the page just seems to be loading but actually doing nothing (loading to infinity).

When I disabled the web-service call in Page_Load, the web-service call after the button click worked well, and if I switched between them (disabled the call in button click and enabled the call in Page_Load) the enabled one worked OK.

How come this is happening? What did I do wrong?
Could it be related to the fact that the location where I published my web-application has some URL-rewriting rules?

---

I don't use (!isPostBack) - I did try to put both calls after the button click event though, and still had the same problem.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyService.Functions service = new MyService.Functions();
    string str = service.DigestURL(Request.RawUrl.ToString());
    ...
}


public void submitButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    MyService.Functions service = new MyService.Functions();
    string str = service.CommitLogIn(usernameText.Text, passwordText.Text);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code segment? Have you used if `(!isPostBack)` in the `Page_Load` for calling the webservice? The `Page_Load` fires when the button is clicked. There might be an issue in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF, make sure you close the client.  I had similar behaviour before when I did not close it.

Comment: I did try service.Abort() and service.Dispose() after calling the web-service for the first time, but still it didn't help...